# Too many math alphabets used in version normal error

Tags: fonts, errors

I have this error Too many math alphabets used in version normal, when I use \usepackage{mathrsfs}. I tried in different ways for example I added

```
\newcommand\hmmax{0}
\newcommand\bmmax{0}
```

in the preamble before including the font packages. And it does not work. This is my preamble

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}   
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[nottoc,notlot,notlof]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{float} 
\usepackage{tkz-fct}
\usepackage[left=2.50cm, right=2.54cm, top=2.54cm, bottom=2.54cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{txfonts}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} 
\fancyhead[LO]{\nouppercase\leftmark} % En las páginas impares, parte izquierda del encabezado, aparecerá el nombre de capítulo
\fancyhead[RE]{\nouppercase\rightmark} % En las páginas pares, parte derecha del encabezado, aparecerá el nombre de sección
\fancyhead[RO,LE]{\thepage} % Números de página en las esquinas de los encabezados
\DeclareSymbolFont{cmsymbols}{OMS}{cmsy}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathcal}{cmsymbols}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathbb}{U}{msb}{m}{n}
\setlength{\parindent}{0mm}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\DeclareMathOperator{\fr}{fr}
\DeclareMathOperator{\interior}{int}
\DeclareMathOperator{\diam}{diam}
\newcommand*\closure[1]{\overline{#1}}
\newcommand{\bd}{\mbox{$\bar{d}$}} 
\usepackage{cleveref}
\DeclareSymbolFont{cmsymbols}{OMS}{cmsy}{m}{n}%
\SetSymbolFont{cmsymbols}{bold}{OMS}{cmsy}{b}{n}%
\DeclareSymbolFont{cmlargesymbols}{OMX}{cmex}{m}{n}%
\SetSymbolFont{cmlargesymbols}{bold}{OMX}{cmex}{b}{n}%%
\DeclareSymbolFont{CMsymbols}{OMS}{cmsy}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{CMsymbols}{bold}{OMS}{cmsy}{b}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\forall}{\mathord}{CMsymbols}{"38}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\exists}{\mathord}{CMsymbols}{"39}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\pi}{\mathord}{letters}{"19}
\DeclareSymbolFont{largesymbols}{OMX}{cmex}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\rbrace} {\mathclose}{cmsymbols}{"67}{cmlargesymbols}{"09}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\lbrace} {\mathopen}{cmsymbols}{"66}{cmlargesymbols}{"08}
\newcommand{\R}{\mbox{$\mathbb{R}$}}
\newcommand{\C}{\mbox{${\mathbb C}$}}
\newcommand{\F}{\mbox{${\mathbb F}$}}
\newcommand{\N}{\mbox{$\mathbb{N}$}}
\newcommand{\Z}{\mbox{${\mathbb Z}$}}
\newcommand{\Q}{\mbox{${\mathbb Q}$}}
\newcommand{\ap}{\mbox{${\phiup}$}}
```

Comment: unrelated to your question (you are simply loading too many fonts, you can only have 16) do not do `\newcommand{\Q}{\mbox{${\mathbb Q}$}}`  that will produce poor subscript and superscript spacing and be slow and produce wrong sizes in sunscripts simply use `\newcommand{\Q}{\mathbb{Q}}`

Comment: Please accept one of the provided answers if your question was answered.

Answer (score 3):

You have defined *several* times the same symbol font; each `\DeclareSymbolFont` declaration uses up a math family.

I reorganized your preamble in sections, so it's easier to spot duplications.

I also added notes about packages not to use. Finally, defining `\R` as `\mbox{$\mathbb{R}$}` is wrong: you'll get normal size also in subscripts, for instance. If the aim is to being able to use `\R` and similar in text, don't: there's no gain in writing `the set \R{} is interesting` instead of `the set $\R$ is interesting` (and editors will color your syntax appropriately). I commented out alternative definitions to enable `\ensuremath`, but, I repeat, don't.

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[left=2.50cm, right=2.54cm, top=2.54cm, bottom=2.54cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
%\usepackage{txfonts} % bad spacings
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} % fixes the wrong bits in txfonts
%\usepackage{amsfonts} % amssymb does it
%\usepackage{amssymb} % not along with newtxmath

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{biblatex}
%\usepackage{enumerate} % not along with enumitem
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage[nottoc,notlot,notlof]{tocbibind}
%\usepackage{physics} % are you sure?
\usepackage{float} 
\usepackage{tkz-fct}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage{cleveref}


%% page styles
\pagestyle{fancy}

\fancyhf{} 
\fancyhead[LO]{\nouppercase\leftmark} % En las páginas impares, parte izquierda del encabezado, aparecerá el nombre de capítulo
\fancyhead[RE]{\nouppercase\rightmark} % En las páginas pares, parte derecha del encabezado, aparecerá el nombre de sección
\fancyhead[RO,LE]{\thepage} % Números de página en las esquinas de los encabezados

% different choices for math
\DeclareSymbolFont{cmsymbols}{OMS}{cmsy}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{cmsymbols}{bold}{OMS}{cmsy}{b}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{cmlargesymbols}{OMX}{cmex}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{cmlargesymbols}{bold}{OMX}{cmex}{b}{n}

\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathbb}{U}{msb}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathcal}{cmsymbols}

\DeclareMathSymbol{\forall}{\mathord}{cmsymbols}{"38}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\exists}{\mathord}{cmsymbols}{"39}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\pi}{\mathord}{letters}{"19}
\DeclareSymbolFont{cmlargesymbols}{OMX}{cmex}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\rbrace} {\mathclose}{cmsymbols}{"67}{cmlargesymbols}{"09}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\lbrace} {\mathopen}{cmsymbols}{"66}{cmlargesymbols}{"08}

% personal commands
\DeclareMathOperator{\fr}{fr}
\DeclareMathOperator{\interior}{int}
\DeclareMathOperator{\diam}{diam}
\newcommand*\closure[1]{\overline{#1}}
\newcommand{\numberset}[1]{\mathbb{#1}}
%\newcommand{\numberset}[1]{\ensuremath{\mathbb{#1}}}% not recommended
\newcommand{\R}{\numberset{R}}
\newcommand{\C}{\numberset{C}}
\newcommand{\F}{\numberset{F}}
\newcommand{\N}{\numberset{N}}
\newcommand{\Z}{\numberset{Z}}
\newcommand{\Q}{\numberset{Q}}
\newcommand{\ap}{\phiup}
%\newcommand{\ap}{\ensuremath{\phiup}}
\newcommand{\bd}{\bar{d}} 
%\newcommand{\bd}{\ensuremath{\bar{d}}}

% various settings
%\setlength{\parindent}{0mm} % why?
```

The highest family number used is 9. You should be OK.

Answer (score 2):

It’s all the `\DeclareSymbolFont` commands, on top of packages such as `ammsymb`.  You only have 16 symbol alphabets in legacy TeX.

One option is to switch to `unicode-math`, which removes this limit completely.

You can also remove those redefinitions of symbol alphabets.  You don’t appear to actually need them.

Usually, if you’re using PDFTeX, you want to pick one math-font package, a matching text-font package, and then load any other alphabets you need with `mathalpha` or `isomath`.  It is very rare that you would ever want to reload `cmex` and so forth.  Are you copying-and-pasting from some other template that loaded one or two symbols from Computer Modern?

For example, if you load a Times-like main font, you probably want to load `newtxmath` with `newtxtext` or `tgpagella` in PDFTeX, or set your math font to TeX Gyre Termes Math and your main font to a clone of Times in LuaTeX.