# Amstext (chemmacros) causes problems in selecting math fonts in chemfig

Tags: fonts, amsmath, chemfig, chemmacros

As the package `typeface` causes fatal error after the LaTeX core updates I have to use the common `\usepackage{font}` to load my favourite set of fonts (see question [Typeface returns fatal coding errors after update of LaTeX core](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/670321/typeface-returns-fatal-coding-errors-after-update-of-latex-core)). As I have quite a few documents that used the `typeface` method of loading fonts and these documents now show a huge amount of errors, I started dissecting them to isolate errors to single or a few conflicting packages.

Unfortunately one of the important packages is causing some serious issues when using certain fonts and formatting structures. I use both the `chemmacros` and `chemfig` packages extensively, so finding a solution to the issues is rather important.

I can prevent the `amsmath.sty` already defined warnings by loading `tcolorbox` as first package or at least before the other font packages. As to why that doesn't work with putting `chemmacros` in front of the font packages, I don't know (although I am intrigued by that).

Using `chemfig` in combination with the fonts `gfsartemisia` and `mathdesign[charter}` causes a few warnings and some very odd behaviour:

1. the fonts `gfsartemisa` and `mathdesign` prevent each other from being used in the output. Loading `gfsartemisia` before `mathdesign` loads the Greek alphabet used by `chemmacros` to be the desired `charter` font, but `gfsartemisia` itself is not used as roman font. The other way around loading `mathdesign` before `gfsartemisia` results in the correct roman font, but an incorrect Greek alphabet. **This behaviour has nothing to do with the `chemfig` package, but it shows in the given MWE.**
2. printing a chemical structure causes the warning / error `too many math fonts` and  prevents the use of the correct formatting. I want the atoms to be displayed in the sansserif font `tgheros` and used the recommended method from the `chemfig` manual page 27: `\renewcommand*\printatom[1]{\ensuremath{\mathsf{#1}}}`. This line does not work now nor does adding a tikz font selection in the `atom style` option. `Chemfig` converts to math mode in `\printatom`, while `atom style` is used to draw the nodes where these atoms are printed in (or something like that).

In the given MWE several annotations have been given to explain the issues found in using `chemfig` together with `gfsartemisia` and `mathdesign`.[image: Chemfig active]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox} % removes amsmath.sty errors: command \iiint already defined when using gfsartemisia and chemmacros

%----- taal/font pakketten
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\usepackage[tracking]{microtype}

\usepackage{gfsartemisia}        % needs to be loaded before mathdesign to prevent greek font switch to default 
\usepackage[charter]{mathdesign} % needs to be loaded before gfsartemisia to prevent roman font switch to default
\usepackage[scale=0.90]{tgheros}

%----- chemische pakketten -----
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\usepackage{chemfig}

%----- grafische pakketten -----
\usepackage{xcolor}
%\usepackage{tikz} % tikz is loaded by chemfig

%----- layout pakketten -----
\usepackage[text={17.0cm,26cm},top=2.0cm,left=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{paracol}

%----- font en versie selectie -----
%\renewcommand*{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\setlength{\parindent}{0mm}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.2}
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{40pt}

\usetikzlibrary{babel,positioning,fit,calc,shapes.misc,arrows.meta,decorations.markings,backgrounds,matrix}

%----- chemistry omgeving -----
\chemsetup{greek=mathdesign,formula=chemformula}
\chemsetup[chemformula]{format=\sffamily}

\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathsf}{OT1}{qhv}{m}{n}       % qag is de LaTeX naam van TG Adventor
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathsf}{bold}{OT1}{qhv}{bx}{n}    % qhv is de LaTeX naam van TG Heros
\renewcommand*\printatom[1]{\ensuremath{\mathsf{#1}}}

\setchemfig{bond style={line width=1pt},atom sep=2.1em, atom style={blue, font=\fontencoding{OT1}\fontfamily{qhv}}}

\begin{document}
    
    \columnratio{0.75,0.25}
    \begin{paracol}{2}
        Hiernaast is de structuurformule van 2,3-dibroomprop-1-een getekend. Als men dit 2,3-dibroomprop-1-een met zinkpoeder behandelt, ontstaat behalve \textit{vast} zinkbromide ook een stof met de molecuulformule \ch{C3H4}, die \textbf{alleen} genoemd wordt. Deze verbinding heeft geen ringstructuur.
        \switchcolumn
        \hfill \chemfig{C(-[2]H)(-[4]H)(-[6]Br)-C(-[6]Br)=C(-[1]H)(-[7]H)}
    \end{paracol}
    
    \vspace{12pt}
    \textsf{check whether Mathdesign - Charter is still used as Greek symbool font:}
    
    \printchemgreekalphabet % listing is not Mathdesign - Charter
    
    and can be used: \ch{\chemalpha-C6H12O6}
    
        
\end{document}
```

**Important note:** I changed the title of the question, because `chemfig` is not the cause, but the victim of the   error caused by the required package `amstext` condition in `chemmacros`. Using the packages `chemgreek` and `chemformula`and their settings to use `mathdesign[charter]` and sansserif in `ch{}` gives the correct `chemfig` output without errors.

Comment: What's the reason for loading `gfsartemisia`? It is the cause of your problems, because for unknown reasons it loads `txfonts`.

Comment: About a decade ago I was introduced into LaTeX writing a pre-university program about quantum chemistry in collaboration with university researchers. Since then I left my Microsoft/CorelDraw/ChemSketch toolbox behind and started to create all my work in LaTeX. Since a few years I use adapted templates for making tests, created / adapted the Orange Book cls files and started writing articles and book chapters using those adapted class templates.

Comment: The fonts `tgheros`, 'gfsartemisia` and 'mathdesign[charter]` were used for chemical structures and headings (sans serif), plain text and amino acid names (serif) and upright/decent delta sign (math). It all worked very well using the `typeface` package. Well, until the update of the core packages that was ... Since then all kinds of problems came to light, which I am addressing now and hope to get them sorted out and preferably solved. Otherwise I have a serious bunch of work that needs to be rewritten .. Which was why I didn't want to use the Microsoft packages anymore to begin with .. ;-P

Comment: `gfsartemisia` has a more playful / pleasant appearance than other serif fonts. Its `k` is not that stiff upper lip `k` present in those others. Would changing `gfsartemisia` to its sister package `gfsartemisia-euler` solve part of the problems? The latter package requires the `euler` font, but doesn't seem to load `txfonts`. @egreg

Comment: @egreg - I substituted `gfsartemisia-euler` for `gfsartemisia` and that worked ... partly. I can't use the `chemmacros` package as stated in the important note. The errors about <too many math fonts ...> return when I use that package again.

Comment: The main problem is: why loading artemisia at all?

Answer (score 0):

As egreg posted his comment about using artimesia at all, a first reaction would be: "why not?". But the comment was intended to get me thinking about why I selected the three fonts in the first place and specifically `gfsartemisia`. I come to that later on.

First, instead of `gfsartemisia` using `gfsartemisia-euler` is the better choice. As egreg pointed out, `gfsartemisa` uses `txfonts` and according to this answer [Too many math alphabets used in version normal error](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/566161/too-many-math-alphabets-used-in-version-normal-error) that is a package better to ignore.

That same question (and many others related to that "*Too many math fonts ..*") also states the limitation of compiling a tex file using (PDF)LaTeX. There is only so much room for loading math fonts. So switching to the XeTeX compiler is the obvious choice. The MWE below compiles without issues tn XeTeX, but will give the "*Too many math fonts ...*" error in PDFLaTeX.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[a4paper,text={18.0cm,26cm},top=2.0cm,left=2.0cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{gfsartemisia-euler}
\usepackage[charter]{mathdesign}
\usepackage[scale=0.92]{tgheros}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{chemfig}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathsf}{T1}{qhv}{m}{n}    % to make sure the TG Heros font is used as sans serif  
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathsf}{bold}{T1}{qhv}{bx}{n} % qhv designates TG Heros
\renewcommand*\printatom[1]{\ensuremath{\mathsf{#1}}}
\setchemfig{bond style={line width=1pt},atom sep=2.1em, atom style={blue}}

\usepackage{chemmacros}
\chemsetup{greek=mathdesign,formula=chemformula}
\chemsetup[chemformula]{format=\sffamily}
  
\begin{document}
    \fontfamily{artemisiaeuler} \selectfont
    
    \lipsum[1][1-3]
    
    \textrm{\lipsum[1][1-3]}
    
    \textsf{\lipsum[1][1-3]}
    
    \begin{equation*}
        \chemmu x \times \chemdelta \alpha = 2 \cdot \Delta \cdot \int_{\alpha}^{\mu} \mathsf{\delta y} \quad {some text} \quad \text{some text} \quad \textrm{some text} \quad \textsf{some text}
    \end{equation*}
    
    \chemfig{H-C([2]-H)([6]-H)-C([2]-H)([6]-H)-C([1]-OH)([7]=O)} or \ch{C3H5COOH} 
    
    \printchemgreekalphabet
        
\end{document}
```

**Remarks**:

1. `mathdesing` should be loaded after `gfsartemisia-euler` as the reverse load order will result in a few errors and warnings.
2. `mathdesign{charter]`will load the `charter` font as default sans serif font. Hence the line `\fontfamily{artemisaeuler} \selectfont` at the start of the document. Using `\textrm{}`however will invoke the `charter` font and not `gfsartemisia-euler`.

These "drawbacks" can be circumvented using the `typeface` package with the patch David Carlisle provided in my question [Typeface returns fatal coding errors after update of LaTeX core](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/670321/typeface-returns-fatal-coding-errors-after-update-of-latex-core) . Replacing the font selection block with

```
\let\MakeUppercasesaved\MakeUppercase
\def\MakeUppercase#1{\expanded{\uppercase{#1}}}

\usepackage[
    typeface=gfsartemisia:euler,
    sanstypeface=tgheros:scale:0.9,
    mathtypeface=mathdesign:charter,
    ]{typeface}

\let\MakeUppercase\MakeUppercasesaved
```

will resolve the font selection. There is no need for the `\fontfamily{artemisiaeuler} \selectfont` line at the start of the document anymore and `\textrm{}` will be using the `artemsiaeuler` font too. The code compiles in (PDF)LaTeX without errors as well.

Finally as to why using `gfsartemisia-euler`. This choice has to do about providing dyslectic students a text that is pleasantly readable. Usually the use of a serif font is not recommended as the dashes on the consonants make the reading of a text difficult (some dyslectic students said that the text seemed to be swirling). But a full sans serif text isn't appreciated either given the "stiff" appearance of most fonts and the condensed spacing when using smaller font sizes. That also influences reading and not only with dyslectic people. `gfsartemisia-euler` is a serif font with characteristics of a sans serif font. It has no dashes across the top/bottom of the consonants and it has a good spacing / broad lettering compared to (sans) serif fonts. Besides ... it looks playful to the reader ...
I couldn't find another font in the LaTeX font catalogue with those characteristics.